# Error BLD00102:No such file or directory 'folder'

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to execute a project Ionic on Visual Studio 2015 but it returns this error:

> BLD00102:No such file or directory 'css'.

I have checked the directory and it exists, I have tried so cleaning cache of Apache-Cordoba but it not works.

> Category -> cordoba-build Description-> BLD00102: No such file or
>   directory 'folder'

Comment: I have got the same error. Still not solved. Let me know if you have got an answer. I will update you too WGH. Refer: :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057161/cordova-project-gives-the-error-bld00102-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: How did you create your Ionic project (e.g. was there a template you used)?